# Running Shell Command in Swift

Tags: macos, swift, shell, applescript

Im attempting to build a swift OSX app that can run some shell commands to mount the users requested VPNs. I tried using NSAppleScript but got an error every time I tried to run with Admin privileges so I decided to use NSTask to call an apple script that will run as admin and mount the VPNs.

In order to debug getting the shell commands working in swift through NSTask I made a test script file that just has a simple whoami command that works when I run it in the script editor and in the terminal using `osascript /Users/amaloney/Desktop/test.scpt`

However in my Swift file

```
import Foundation

let task = NSTask();
task.launchPath = "/usr/bin/osascript"
task.arguments = ["/Users/amaloney/Desktop/test.scpt"]

task.launch()
```

I continue to get the following error

*script error -54.  Couldn't get error text because of error -1700.*

Any thoughts on how I can get this working?

Thanks!

For reference - test.scpt

`do shell script "whoami"`

Comment: Are you waiting for the command to finish with `task.waitUntilExit()`?

Comment: @Kametrixom I've tried running with that as well, same error

Comment: http://lists.apple.com/archives/applescript-users/2001/Mar/msg01286.html

Comment: @ThomasKilian Ive read thorough that already, that user is getting error -2741 which I am not.

Comment: Have you tried using bash or Perl instead of Applescript?

Answer (score 1):

I was running this in an Xcode Playground, which apparently was the source of the problems. Once I went ahead and integrated this code into my OSX app it worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

The issues appear to be related to the `AppleScript` portions of your code:

1. `script error -54`

   > ↳ -54     File permission error
2. `Couldn't get error text because of error -1700.`

   > ↳ Can’t make ... into type item.

It's likely your script tries to perform an operation that it doesn't have permission to do, and also tries to assign the wrong type — Without seeing the script or knowing what it does it's unknown.

Comment: I suspected this as well but I cant seem to find any problems with my script -- do shell script "whoami"

Comment: If you want to use `AppleScript` with `NSTask` then the command needs to be absolute: `do shell script "/usr/bin/whoami"`... The whoami utility is obsolete anyway, so you could use `/usr/bin/id` with `NSTask` instead, then AppleScript is not needed.

Comment: My end goal is not to use whoami, that was just something simple for a test. My plan is to execute some jamf commands from within my swift app

Comment: Most `NSTasks` can work similarly; hopefully this has given you a better understanding of the prcoess.